# Integrate $\int x^{\sin x} \, (1+ x \cos x \ln (x)+ \sin x ) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$f(x) = x^{\sin x} \, (1+ x \cos x \ln (x) + \sin x)$
Integrate this function pls.

I know the answer but not the method

the answer is 
$x\cdot x^{\sin(x)}$

Comment: You mean this: $$\int x^{\sin(x)}\left(1+x\cos(x)\ln(x)+\sin(x)\right)\space\text{d}x$$

Comment: Let $u=x^{\sin(x)+1}$ then you find out the entire integrand is $du$ :)

Comment: These types of function usually comes from derivative of $f(x)^g(x)$ so it's not too hard to guess the answer.

Comment: differentiate the answer to guess the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
y&:=x^{\sin x}\\
\ln y &= \sin x \ln x \\
\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx}&=\cos x\ln x + \sin x \frac{1}{x} \\
 \frac{dy}{dx} &= x^{\sin x} \left(\sin x  \frac{1}{x} + \cos x \ln x\right)
\end{align*}
Now put go back to the integral.

\begin{align*}
I &= \int x^{\sin(x)}\left(1+x\cos(x)\ln(x)+\sin(x)\right)dx \\
&=\int x^{\sin x} + x\left(x^{\sin x} \left(\sin x  \frac{1}{x} + \cos x \ln x\right) \right) dx\\
&= \int y + x\frac{dy}{dx} dx \\ &= \int \frac{d}{dx}\left(xy\right) dx \\ &= \int d(xy) \\ &=xy +C = \color{red}{x\cdot x^{\sin x}+C}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite:
$$\int \:x^{\sin(x)}\sin(x)+x^{\sin(x)+1}\cos(x)\ln(x)+x^{\sin(x)}dx$$
Apply linearity:
$$\int \:x^{\sin(x)}\sin(x)dx+\int \:x^{\sin(x)+1}\cos(x)\ln(x)dx+\int \:x^{\sin(x)}dx$$
Now:
$\int \:x^{\sin(x)}dx\rightarrow$ integrate by parts

$f'=1$, $g = x^{\sin(x)}$

$f = x$ $g = x^{\sin \left(x\right)}\left(\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}+\cos \left(x\right)\ln \left(x\right)\right)$